# Selenium, using find_element but end up with half the website

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I finished the linked tutorial and tried to modify it to get somethings else from a different website.  I am trying to get the margin table of HHI but the website is coded in a strange way that I am quite confused.

I find the child element of the parent that have the text with xpath://a[@name="HHI"], its parent is `<font size="2"></font>` and contains the text I wanted but there is a lot of tags named exactly `<font size="2"></font>` so I can't just use xpath://font[@size="2"].

Attempt to use the full xpath would print out half of the website content.

the full xpath:

`/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/pre/font/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/pre/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font/font`

Is there anyway to select that particular font tag and print the text?

website:
https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/market/rm/rm_dcrm/riskdata/margin_hkcc/merte_hkcc.htm

Tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXMJ6FS7llk&t=8740s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd
# prepare it to automate
from datetime import datetime
import os
import sys
import csv

application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable) # export the result to the same file as the executable

now = datetime.now() # for modify the export name with a date
month_day_year = now.strftime("%m%d%Y") # MMDDYYYY

website = "https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/market/rm/rm_dcrm/riskdata/margin_hkcc/merte_hkcc.htm"
path = "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Automate with Python – Full Course for Beginners/venv/Scripts/chromedriver.exe"

# headless-mode
options = Options()
options.headless = True

service = Service(executable_path=path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get(website)

containers = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value='') # or find_elements

hhi = containers.text # if using find_elements, = containers[0].text

print(hhi)
```

Update:

Thank you to Conal Tuohy, I learn a few new tricks in Xpath.  The website is written in a strange way that even with the Xpath that locate the exact `font` tag, the result would still print all text in every following tags.

I tried to make a list of different products by `.split("Back to Top")`  then slice out the first item and use `.split("\n")`.  I will `.split()` the lists within list until it can neatly fit into a dataframe with strike prices as index and maturity date as column.

Probably not the most efficient way but it works for now.

```
product = "HHI"

containers = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value=f'//font[a/@name="{product}"]')

hhi = containers.text.split("Back to Top")

# print(hhi)

hhi1 = hhi[0].split("\n")

df = pd.DataFrame(hhi1)

# print(df)

df.to_csv(f"{product}_{month_day_year}.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right that HTML is just awful! But if you're after the text of the table, it seems to me you ought to select the text node that follows the `B` element that follows the `a[@name="HHI"]`; something like this:

```xml
//a[@name="HHI"]/following-sibling::b/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

EDIT

Of course that XPath won't work in Selenium because it identifies a text node rather than an element. So your best result is to return the font element that directly contains the `//a[@name="HHI"]`, which will include some cruft (the `<a href="#TableTop">Back to Top</a>` link, etc) but which will at least contain the tabular data you want:

```xml
//a[@name="HHI"]/parent::font
```

i.e. "the parent `font` element of the `a` element whose `name` attribute equals `HHI`"

or equivalently:

```xml
//font[a/@name="HHI"]
```

i.e. "the `font` element which has, among its child `a` elements, one whose `name` attribute equals `HHI`"

Comment: The result of the xpath expression "//a[@name="HHI"]/following-sibling::b/following-sibling::text()[1]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element,  do I need to use something other than selenium to use this xpath?

Comment: @Stephen ah of course you're right! Selenium will not execute that XPath for you. I will update my answer.

Comment: @ Conal Tuohy thank you for the Xpath tricks, I find a way to get a result and make an update.